# How to get send the bots name in python using python-telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

**I'm building a bot using python-telegram-bot in which on my bot info command I need
my bot to print its name on Name Section**

> My Test code

```
def info(update, context):
    user = update.message.from_user
    info_string = f'''
  @{user.username}
✯  : {context.bot.name}
✯ : --
✯ :  
✯  :  
✯  : 
✯  : v2.0
'''
    
    img = 'https://telegra.ru.com/p/e74261e8x916320db94d2b30b241cddf245e669a64b26be2'
    buttonu = ButtonMaker()
    buttonu.sbutton("Mirror Group", 'aebx')
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttonu.build_menu(1))
    sendImgz(img, info_string, context.bot, update.message, reply_markup)
```

it is showing error

```
2022-07-25 08:51:40,319 - bot - ERROR - Can't parse entities: unexpected end of name token at byte offset 126
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a parse error in the info message. in my opinion the error is not in the `user` variable but in the `info_string`.

Can you try to send only the `user` and `context.bot.name` in to the message instead all of that symbol?

Otherwise try to log the variable in the console before send so you are sure nothing is interfere

Comment: info_string = f'''
  @{user.username}
✯  : {context.bot.name}
✯ : --
✯ :  
✯  :  
✯  : 
✯  : v2.0
''' 
this is the info string what is the parse error

if its with the  sendImgz(img, info_string, context.bot, update.message, reply_markup)
then the paste type is html

Comment: also @peter {user.name} works but the context.bot.name is the only thing which isn't working

Comment: yes, can you try set the `info_string` as: `info_string = f''' MY NAME: {context.bot.name}'''` NOTE that MY NAME is not in special char